# How to choose default file to open on github repository page URL?

Tags: github, repository

Well I am new to GitHub and confused with this, I have created a repository and created a page https://anilkatwal.github.io/hello-world/.   Now it have two files on master branch , README.md and index.html . While opening default page (https://anilkatwal.github.io/hello-world/) it opens index.html file But how can I change it show that it can open another file lets say README.md (On default URL) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my past experience, I was able to *delete* the `index.html` file and create a `index.md` file for a *single page* site for GitHub pages. You could keep the `README.md` file in your reposiory, but it wouldn't the *landing page* of the site.

Basically,
One page sites can be achieved with a single `index.md`.

Check [this on GitHub's site/docs](https://help.github.com/en/github/working-with-github-pages/creating-a-github-pages-site#creating-your-site).